# password_hash is deprecated since PHP 7.0.0?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm using *[php for visual studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.PHPToolsforVisualStudio)*, I was creating a sign-up form. When I was about to use the `password_hash` *build-in* PHP function, it showed me the following comment:

[image]

But when executing the function it works fine.

There is no information what so ever about it being deprecated in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7) 
>   password_hash — Creates a password hash

Am I missing something?

Comment: this is just too weird.

Comment: Uhh, no. I think something's squiffy with your IDE.

Comment: I hope so @Sammitch. Would be wierd when they just suddenly decide to remove it :o

Comment: It's apparently getting confused because the `salt` part of the `$options`  array is deprecated.

Comment: Btw, the word is "deprecated" and not "depecrated". I fixed that earlier but was overwritten.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I inserted a link to the PHP manual. Will fix it. Probaly overwritten your edit.

Comment: Ok, seems like a wrong comment then by the authors of the plugin php toolfs for visual studio.

Comment: I doubt that anyone actually touched a keyboard to make that mistake, they likely just scraped PHP.net and fed it to a bot. You should file a bug with them so that this gets fixed and doesn't lead others down the wrong path.

Comment: time to not use visual studio

Comment: hehe, no I like it as I also use it for .NET and the IDE is quiet good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems like a misreading of the [password_hash() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which states:

> **Warning** The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

and

> **Caution** It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.
>
> As noted above, providing the salt option in PHP 7.0 will generate a deprecation warning. Support for providing a salt manually may be removed in a future PHP release.

---

Rest assured, `password_hash()` isn't deprecated (at the time of writing this).

Comment: Alright, seems to me too. Wanted to make sure, as the comment was very confusing. Also the red underline it has under the function :|